# Microsoft JScript throws 'variable' is undefined error when setting variable to undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm setting a variable in Microsoft JScript to another variable that is undefined, i.e.,

var valid = Page_IsValid;

JScript throws the following error

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Page_IsValid' is undefined

Somehow this doesn't strike me as correct. Shouldn't it just ignore the assignment -- I don't do anything with Page_IsValid beyond assigning it to the variable.

Comment: Could you show us your script. I don't seem to have an issue with that. Can it be that `Page_IsValid` is out of scope? EDIT: ah.. I see when you said "variable that is undefined" you meant "undefined variable", not "variable which value is undefined". Wow. My reading comprehension is wack today.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct behavior.  You can reference a new variable without the `var` keyword so long as your first reference is an assignment (e.g., `firstReference = 'foo';`), or in a `typeof` expression.  This is because you are still declaring the variable, but as a global.  In your case, you are trying to use `Page_IsValid` on the right-hand of the assignment, but the interpreter has no idea what to do with it, because it hasn't been delcared anywhere.

If you're unsure whether or not `Page_IsValid` will have been declared or not, you can do something like this:

```
// kind of funky to set the value to undefined, but this ensures
// that Page_IsValid has been properly "declared"
if (typeof Page_IsValid === 'undefined') { Page_IsValid = undefined; }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected behaviour, your attempting to assign something that does not exist.
You can test the state of `Page_IsValid` and handle it as neccesary:

```
var valid = (typeof Page_IsValid !== 'undefined') ? Page_IsValid : <default value>;
```